# How to call an class's included module function from a rake?

Tags: ruby, rake

I am in a task in a rake file.

```
# gottaRunThis.rake
task [:var] => :environment do |t, args|

    Foo::Bar::Bell::this_function(args.var)
    #runs Bell::this_function(var) but fails to complete.
    # errors out with the words:
    # NoMethodError: undefined method `put' for nil:NilClass
    # Because Bell needs a @connection variable that doesn't exist in
    # it's context when called directly.
end
```

The thing is, the target module and def are meant to be included in another class.

```
# mainclass.rb
module Foo
  module Bar
    class TheMainClass
      include Foo::Bar::Bell
      def initialize
        @site = A_STATIC_SITE_VARIABLE
        @connection = self.connection
      end
      def connection
        # Connection info here, too verbose to type up
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And `Bell` looks like.

```
# bell.rb
module Foo
  module Bar
    module Bell
    def do_the_thing(var)
      #things happen here
      #var converted to something here
      response = @connection.put "/some/restful/interface, var_converted
    end
  end
end
```

Should I modify `Bell` so it somehow is including `TheMainClass`? (And if so, I don't know how?) Or is there some syntax I should use in my rake file like

```
Foo::Bar::TheMainClass::Bell::do_the_thing(args.var)
#I don't think this works... should it? What would the equivilent but working version look like?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Included methods are available as instance methods, so you can call `do_the_thing` like this:

```
main_class = Foo::Bar::TheMainClass.new
main_class.do_the_thing(args.var)
```

Comment: I get NoMethodError: undefined method `do_the_thing' for Foo::Bar::TheMainClass:Class ?

Comment: could you share the backtrace? It looks that you called it on a class not on the instance

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `do_the_thing' for Foo::Bar::TheMainClass:Class
/app/lib/tasks/gottaRunThis.rake:12:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'

Comment: And what is the line 12 in the rake task file?

Comment: this_instance.do_the_thing(args.var)   <--- this line

Comment: which is preceeded by this line: this_instance = Foo::Bar::TheMainClass.new

Comment: It's strange, could share the the whole new version of the code on a gist? I can't understand why the method is called on a class

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but that's pretty much all the applicable code already. I'll have to triple-check through, maybe I've got a typo somewhere.

Comment: Ahh, yep. In bell.rb, I missed a bit when I typed, it wasn't def do_the_thing(var), it was self.def do_the_thing. Removing the self fixed it. So it was an unrelated error. Thanks!